For the third time: I don’t know what to buy!
This is the sequel to this puzzle.

My cryptic and rude roommate asked me to buy something AGAIN!
“What am I supposed to buy?” I grumpily ask.
“What is the knight risking?” He replies.
I pause.
“Just buy the dam meat, WILL YOU!?!” He then stated.
“Stop being rude!” I exclaim.
What was I supposed to buy?

Leaning on the "risking" part of the clue:

 Sirloin Steak


How did I miss the betting angle?

Correct! Well done!

Could you explain how you got to this?  I understand the first and third syllables, but not the second.

@RyanM  Nor do I, other than that it  completes the knight's name:  "Sir X".

@RyanM well, who was the meatiest knight at the table?

Not sure how close this is

 Sir Loin Chops
 or
Sir Loin Cuts


Very close. It’s not a chop though.

Added an alternative.
